# Get values of Excel Cells in C# including blank cells

Tags: c#, excel

I'm trying to get all Excel selected range values including blank entries. What I have worked until is,when a blank is hit and then it exits the loop. I need to recognize the blank, do something with it and then go on to the next cell in the selected range.

This is my code:

```
// Get active excel instance
                Excel.Application xlApp = (Excel.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
                // Get active excel workbook
                string wbn = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook.Name;
                Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook = (Excel.Workbook)xlApp.ActiveWorkbook;
                // Get active excel worksheet
                Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.ActiveSheet;
                // Get range of values from Excel
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range SelectedRange = xlApp.Selection as Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range;
                string[] ExcelSelection = new string[1000]; 
                int counter = 0;
                foreach (object cell in xlApp.Selection.Cells)        //original loop stopping when it hits a blank cell                   
                {
                    try
                    {                                                 
                        ExcelSelection[counter] = ((Excel.Range)cell).Value2.ToString().Trim();                 
                        //run query to return SAP Description for Excel Active Cell Text
                        dataGridView1.DataSource = GetSAPDescription(ExcelSelection[counter]);
                        counter++;
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: It is probably because you immediately use `.ToString()`. Might want to check if it has value before calling `.ToString()`

Comment: This seemed to fix it. Thanks Bas!

Comment: No problem, glad I could be of help!